# How to get status when order is updated in Magento?

Tags: magento

I need to set a function/trigger that will send response to another site (URL that I'll define, for example http://mysite.com/orders/:orderid/cancelled) from Magento - when an order status is updated OR a credit memo is created. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the Magento events? I think **catalog_product_status_update** and **sales_creditmemo_item_save_after** sound promising?

Regards

Comment: This is the right approach. However, a word to the wise -- unless he uses an asynchronous request, this could make all orders significantly slower since it's now waiting on an external service.

Comment: What do you mean with external service?

Comment: "I need to set a function/trigger that will send response to another site (URL that I'll define for example http://mysite.com/orders/:orderid/cancelled) from Magento" -- if @Irena is referring to another site/URL different from the present URL, it would be external.

Comment: Ah, yes of course, you are right :). But still, using events and an observer is the Magento way to handle those things.

Comment: Agreed! Just pointing out the risk, since yours is the right answer.